# Python re.sub remove only parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove parenthesis in a sentence which can contain emoticone. For example,

> " this game is awesome but expensive($100) :("

. How can I obtain this on python :

> "this game is awesome but expensive $100 :("

Comment: Nice problem! What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What about `(?<!:)[()]`?

Comment: How about removing paired parentheses? `re.sub(r'\s*\(([^)]*)\)', r' \1', s)`

Comment: I only find a way on internet to remove the parenthesis but it removes also its contain re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', ' ', string)

Comment: @Rawing and ctwheels . Thank you that works well! How do you obtain your result ? I know only simple basis of regex :/

Comment: @Shiro I typically use https://regex101.com for testing.

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

Your best bet is to create a regex for all the possible emoticons. The regular expressions below should help you formulate a pattern that matches the emoticons you need.

---

### Code

You can use either of the following:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YUfYwY/2)

```
(?<!:)[()]
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YUfYwY/4)

```
\b[()]|[()]\b
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<!:)[()]` Matches a `(` or `)` where the preceding character is not `:`
- `\b[()]|[()]\b` Matches a `(` or `)` where a word boundary position is found on either the left or right side of the character

Comment: @Jan I was thinking about that initially, but let's assume emojis can be inserted into parentheses as well. In that case, the parenthesis balancing will fail. That's why I decided to go another route and assume that balancing parentheses doesn't always work and that the OP should be looking for specific strings instead (`:(`, `:)`, etc.) and selecting the parentheses that don't match those criteria.